# Функция random_shuffle(first,last,random)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

В *С++*  есть функция, перетасовывающая последовательность `random_shuffle()`. Как правило, она используется с двумя аргументами.
Однако, есть версия с тремя аргументами.

Как её использовать с этими тремя аргументами?

Третьим аргументом является "функция генератор случайных чисел". По идее, этот третий аргумент - функтор. Только какой? В инструкции написано, что этот функтор должен возвращать для `n` элементов значение в диапазоне `[0,n]`.

Я попытался написать что-то вроде функтора. Компилирует, но не работает. Ошибка времени выполнения. Вот код:

```
using namespace std ;


    template<class T>
    class Func{
        T num ;
    public :
        Func(T & a  )
            :num(a)
        {}
        T & operator()( T & x)
        { x = (T)((rand())%(int)x) ;
            return  x ;}
    } ;

const int NUM =12 ;

int main(void)
{

    int sz = NUM ;

    vector<int> vec ;

    int i =0;
    for(i =0;i<NUM;++i)
        vec.push_back(rand()) ;

    int g = sz-1 ;

    Func<int> f(g) ;


    random_shuffle(vec.begin() , vec.end() , f ) ;
// Здесь возникает ошибка времени выполнения.

return 0 ;
}
```

**Показываю то, что у меня получилось**

```
{

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<set>
#include<ctime>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>

using namespace std ;

// Функтор (недорезанный). Но рабочий !!!
// Это ПЛОХОЙ Функтор !!!
// Он НЕ МОЖЕТ применяться БЕЗ ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОГО
// указания Аргумента.
    template<class T>
    class Func_1{
        T num ;
    public :
        Func_1(const T & a  )
            :num(a)
        {}
        T  operator()(const T & x){return rand()%x ;}
        // СРАБОТАЛО!!!
    } ;


// Этот Функтор работает ТОЛЬКО для ТИПА "int" !!!
    class Func_2
    {
    public :
        int operator()(const int & x)
        {
            return rand()%x ;
        }
    };


// Вот как должен выглядеть НОРМАЛЬНЫЙ Функтор !!!
    template<class T>
    class Func_3 : unary_function<T,T>
    {
    public:
        T operator()(T & x)
        {
            return (T) rand()%x ;
        }
    } ;


    // Константа КОЛИЧЕСТВА Циклов.
    const int NUM = 12 ;

int main( void )
{
    cout << "\n\n\tBEGIN !!!\n\n" << endl ;

    srand((int)time(0)) ;

    vector<int> vec_base , vec_1 , vec_2 , vec_3  ;
    set<int> s_temp ;

    while(s_temp.size()<NUM+1)
        s_temp.insert(rand()%100) ;

    set<int>::iterator sb = s_temp.begin() ;

    while(sb != s_temp.end())
    {
        vec_base.push_back(*sb) ;
        vec_1.push_back(*sb) ;
        vec_2.push_back(*sb) ;
        vec_3.push_back(*sb) ;
        ++sb ;
    }


    cout << "\n\tSORT VEC_base:\n" << endl ;

    vector<int>::iterator vb = vec_base.begin() ;

    int v =0;
    for(v =0;v<NUM;++v)
    {
        cout << "\t" << v+1 << " . " << *vb << endl ;
        ++vb ;
    }


    cout << "\t\tRANDOM_SHUFFLE(1,2):\n\n" << endl ;

    cout << "\n\n\tNOT SORT VEC_base:\n" << endl ;

    random_shuffle(vec_base.begin() , vec_base.end()) ;

    vb = vec_base.begin() ;
    v =0 ;
    for(v =0 ;v<NUM ; ++v)
    {
        cout << "\t" << v+1 << " . " << *vb << endl ;
        ++vb ;
    }


    cout << "\n\t\tRANDOM_SHUFFLE(1,2,3):\n" << endl ;


// Так делать следует только для ПЛОХОГО Функтора !!!
// Этот ПЛОХОЙ Функтор ТРЕБУЕТ ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОГО указания Аргумента !!!

    int g = NUM ;
    Func_1<int> f(g) ;

// Это всё не годится !!!
// НОРМАЛЬНЫЕ Функторы НЕ ДОЛЖНЫ самостоятельно Аргументы !!!
// Их Аргументы инициализируются Алгоритмами !!!
//  Func_2ft(g) ;
//  Func_3<int> fn(g) ;

// Это ПЛОХОЙ Функтор. Он не может применяться без аргумента!!!

    random_shuffle(vec_1.begin() , vec_1.end() , Func_1<int>(g) ) ;


// Нормальные Функторы следует применять БЕЗ Аргумента !!!

    random_shuffle(vec_2.begin() , vec_2.end() , Func_2() ) ;
    random_shuffle(vec_3.begin() , vec_3.end() , Func_3<int>() ) ;


    vb = vec_1.begin() ;
    cout << "\n\n\tNOT SORT VEC_1:\n" << endl ;
    v =0 ;
    for(v =0 ; v<NUM ; ++v)
    {
        cout << "\t" << v+1 << " . " << *vb << endl ;
        ++vb ;
    }

    vb = vec_2.begin() ;
    cout << "\n\n\tNOT SORT VEC_2:\n" << endl ;
    v =0 ;
    for(v =0 ; v<NUM ; ++v)
    {
        cout << "\t" << v+1 << " . " << *vb << endl ;
        ++vb ;
    }

    vb = vec_3.begin() ;
    cout << "\n\n\tNOT SORT VEC_3:\n" << endl ;
    v =0 ;
    for(v =0 ; v<NUM ; ++v)
    {
        cout << "\t" << v+1 << " . " << *vb << endl ;
        ++vb ;
    }
    v =0 ;


    cout << "\n\n\tEND !!!\n\n" << endl ;
return (0) ;
}


}
```

Comment: Проблема явно кроется здесь: `x = (T)((rand())%(int)x);` - вы изменяете значение принятого по ссылке аргумента х.

Comment: Сработало !!! Спасибо !!!

Comment: В таком случае, если вопрос решён - закрывайте его.

Comment: И кстати, что конкретно сработало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [документации](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/), реализация функции `random_shuffle` может выглядеть так:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class RandomNumberGenerator>
  void random_shuffle (RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last,
                       RandomNumberGenerator& gen)
{
  iterator_traits<RandomAccessIterator>::difference_type i, n;
  n = (last-first);
  for (i=n-1; i>0; --i) {
    swap (first[i],first[gen(i+1)]);
  }
}
```

Из этого примера следует, что функция (класс-функтор) `gen` должна иметь примерно следующую сигнатуру:

```
int your_function(int) // функция

class Your_class // функтор
{
  public:
    int operator() (int);
}
```

Функция принимает на вход максимально возможную позицию элемента - т.е. размер коллекции, и возвращает новую позицию, которая должна иметь значение от 0 до значения принятого аргумента.

В простейшем варианте реализация такова:

```
int myrandom (int i) { return rand() % i;}
```

Comment: Моя проблема заключалась в том, что я пытался искусственно присвоить функтору аргумент, в то время, как Алгоритм, использующй этот функтор,  делает это самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

Моя проблема заключалась в том, что я пытался присвоить функтору свой собственный аргумент, в то время, как алгоритм, использующий функтор, - делает это самостоятельно.
КСТАТИ. Алгоритм "random_shuffle()" не только тасует последовательность, но и изменяет значение одного из её членов. ЭТО СТРАННО.

Comment: Алгоритм "random_shuffle()" не должен изменять значений элементов. Наверно, в ваш код закралась ещё ошибка. Напишите входную последовательность и результат работы.

Comment: Уважаемые Господа!

Comment: Уважаемые Господа! Я ещё раз проверил работу всех версий функции "random_shuffle()". К моему ВЕЛИКОМУ СЧАСТЬЮ никаких вышеупомянутых отклонений я не обнаружил. Так что вопрос считаю исперченным. ВСЕМ БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО !!!